# camel expression - simple expression with header value as an argument

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to set camel Header value using below Expression

```
 .setHeader("amqName").simple("${amqAddressMap.get(header.userTypeID)}", String.class)
```

where amqAddressMap is an array list and passing header value as argument but it shows invalid expression error

is there any way to execute the code without using using processor class

Comment: Hi! I think you need to have `${amqAddressMap.get(${header.userTypeID})}`

Comment: @Screwtape not working ...

Comment: @Screwtape is correct. Also how is `amqAddressMap` declared? My blind guess is it is your local java variable and you cannot do that, you can only access objects stored in Exchange. Use `setProperty("amqAddressMap", constant(amqAddressMap))` and then you can refer it with `${exchangeProperty.amqAddressMap.get(${header.userTypeID})}`. And I am pretty sure that the exception message tells a bit more, than "invalid expression error"

Comment: @Screwtape Setting property fixed the issue. Thanks. Can you make it as an answer.

Comment: @Bedla - I think this is yours... if you want it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access ArrayList inside exchange we need to set it as a property

```
setProperty("amqAddressMap", constant(amqAddressMap))
```

So that we can access it using EL like

```
${exchangeProperty.amqAddressMap.get(${header.userTypeID})}
```